# How to replace one object for another in Vuejs? Interface not changing

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

i am doing an app in Vuejs and i am stuck with a problem in replacing one object for another that comes from an API every 10 seconds. I have this at the moment:

```
watch: {
 myObj() {
  for (let [key, tuner] of Object.entries(myObj)) {
   ---- some code ----
  }
 }
},
},
created() {
 setInterval(this.callMyApi(), 10000);
},
```

I am watching the object and then use it in a for loop that does some logic. I saw the documentation mention using 'this.$set()' but this only adds a property to the object and i want replace one for another. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add the structure of your data object.

Comment: Try the deep and handler property if its an object that you are watching - https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

`this.myObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newObj))`

to make a deep copy of the object inside `this.callMyApi()`.

To watch for changes on this object do the following: create a new bool variable and use it on the component you want to update:

```html
<componenttoupdate :reactto=objupdated/>
```

```js
data: {
    ...
    objupdated: false
    ...
}
```

and switch the objupdated bool state anytime you do the deep copy on your function, and so the component will update.

This is a cheaper solution than keeping watchers over large objects that may get updated very often as yours.